# Convert data into a pandas DataFrame and remove some

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, autonumeric.js

I've a data set of measurement to convert into dataframe of float values. But sometimes the machine does not measurement and set a "---" character which give pandas.to_numeric ValueError.
For a reduced exemple here, my question is how to convert to float a hole columns and delete where I've a string "---" character set :

```
data = {'row_1': ["3.0", "2.4", "---", "0.0"], 'row_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

How to delete the entire third line and convert the row_1 values to float ? Thanks.

Comment: `df = df.drop(2)` (dropping by index). And `df['row_1'] = df['row_1'].astype(float)`.

Comment: Yep ok. But my real dataframe initially is of 20 000 rows x 36 columns ! So I cannot set it mannually...

Comment: I realised that a bit later; see my answer, which is more systematic: it converts the triple dashes to something that Pandas will interpret as NaNs, from which the rest follows straightforwardly.

Comment: Note that if you are reading from e.g. a CSV file, you can use a parameter like `na_values` to add "---" as a value that will be interpreted as a NaN. Which would be better than converting things later on. But I don't know how you obtain the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Convert to floating point, but first make sure triple dashes can be interpreted as NaNs
df['row_1'] = df['row_1'].replace('---', 'NaN').astype(float)

# drop rows with NaNs
df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: It's also another perfect solution ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'row_1': ["3.0", "2.4", "---", "0.0"], 'row_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df = df[df['row_1']!='---'].copy()
df['row_1'] = df['row_1'].astype(float)
```

Comment: Well done. Is there a way to do so with a column name with spaces like "Temp Out" ?

Comment: @CedM Use df["Temp Out"]. I'll edit the answer

Comment: It's perfect ! Many thanks.